# Excel 2007 VBA: Event refires after the same event procedure ends

Tags: vba, excel, events

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Some code

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The "some code" is used to trap when a user has pasted some value in some cell. If the paste came after a copy operation then the procedures works correctly. If the paste value came after a cut operation then after execution reaches End Sub the procedures starts again and I cannot determine what change is occuring to cause the refire.

The source and destination cells are formatted with Data Validation.

Comment: did you try the deleting the data validation and then stepping through code?

Comment: Yes. Did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you can see that the first event fired is from the range which was cut, and the second is from the paste destination.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Debug.Print Sh.Name, Source.Address()

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So the question then becomes, why are two events being triggered when EnableEvents = False? Are there two events that are buffered and executes after the first one is finished? And how do I resolve this? One other thing of note: as a temporary workaround I implemented a flag in a different worksheet so I could detect the refire and exit the sub (chagrin) before any code was executed. Oddly enough changing the flag's value in the worksheet solved the refire (and of course the code to evaluate the flag was never engaged).

Comment: @DatManCoo cut happens before your sheet change, and paste happens after. Why don't you use the event at the end for your code? Does xl provide a built in event procedure for paste destination?

Comment: In the event raised by the Cut part of the operation the range `Source` will have no content, so can you not just ignore that event?

Comment: Update1: My previous comment about my attempt at a workaround by using a flag in a worksheet DID NOT inadvertently solve the problem - it was late in the day when I implemented the workaround and I did not have time to test thoroughly. Further testing the next day revealed my erroneous initial conclusion.

Comment: Update2: I now see why there are two events to deal with when a cut and paste operation is performed. This seems to be a poor approach on Microsoft's part but hey, who am I to judge...I am sure the developers had their reasons.

Comment: whytheq...as per my Update2, these events fire simultaneously and there is no event that captures either specifically - you have to use a more general event such as Workbook_SheetChange or Worksheet_Change. Once the first event finishes the second one begins.

Comment: whytheq...when I said these events fire simultaneously, what I mean is that they are trapped simultaneously fire in succession so you can't intercept them.

Comment: TimW...it may be Monday before I get a chance to look at checking out your suggestion.